# Converting Complex XML into a usable format in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, xml, xslt, ssis

I've been learning SQL Server (painfully and slowly), and finally got the damn thing to do what I want to by and large, but there's one XML import process that's tripping me up. I have a complex XML file, as sampled (more details on this XML can be found here: http://wiki.eve-id.net/APIv2_Corp_AssetList_XML):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<eveapi version="2">
  <currentTime>2010-12-19 07:15:16</currentTime>
  <result>
    <rowset name="assets" key="itemID" columns="itemID,locationID,typeID,quantity,flag,singleton">
      <row itemID="961254083" locationID="30001161" typeID="17177" quantity="1" flag="0" singleton="1" />
      <row itemID="961256074" locationID="30001161" typeID="27672" quantity="1" flag="0" singleton="1" />
      <row itemID="1270658107" locationID="30002583" typeID="17176" quantity="1" flag="0" singleton="1" />
      <row itemID="1000474513775" locationID="30002583" typeID="17407" quantity="1" flag="0" singleton="1">
        <rowset name="contents" key="itemID" columns="itemID,typeID,quantity,flag,singleton">
          <row itemID="1000515794105" typeID="255" quantity="1" flag="27" singleton="1" />
        </rowset>
      </row>
      <row itemID="1000474513607" locationID="30002583" typeID="17406" quantity="1" flag="0" singleton="1">
        <rowset name="contents" key="itemID" columns="itemID,typeID,quantity,flag,singleton">
          <row itemID="1000515772705" typeID="17686" quantity="1" flag="27" singleton="1" />
        </rowset>
      </row>
    </rowset>
  </result>
  <cachedUntil>2010-12-19 23:40:24</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
```

So, naturally SSIS snarks at me when I try to import this using the XML Source tool as it's 'complex' XML (mumble grumble). Ideally what I'd like to have happen is to be able to get this thing into a SSIS data flow so I can dump it into a table in my SQL database. The funky stuff comes in with the additional nested rows, these are items nested within other items, and I'd like to retain the nesting information. Ideally what I'd like to do is have a new column created that includes the itemID of the parent item, and would be 0 or null if it's at the top level. This would also require duplicating the locationID of the parent item.

Ergo, the final output would be a table with the following rows: itemID, locationID, typeID, quantity, flag, singleton, parentID. Given the above example input, the output should look something like this (assuming .csv format):

```
itemID, locationID, typeID, quantity, flag, singleton, parentID
961254083, 30001161, 17177, 1, 0, 1, 0
961256074, 30001161, 27672, 1, 0, 1, 0
1270658107, 30002583, 17176, 1, 0, 1, 0
1000474513775, 30002583, 17407, 1, 0, 1, 0
1000515794105, 30002583, 255, 1, 27, 1, 1000474513775
1000474513607, 30002583, 17406, 1, 0, 1, 0
1000515772705, 30002583, 17686, 1, 27, 1, 1000474513607
```

From what I've been googling (aah the wonderful power of google) this may be possible with an XSLT, but my knowledge of such things is rather insignificant at the moment, having just learned how to use SSIS and play with XML files in this way about two weeks ago. I'm hoping to get a little help on either building an XSLT file that can do this conversion, or another way that may work better.

One additional note: Whatever the solution, it cannot involve any sort of manual entry. I'm doing this to migrate away from a manual entry system, so any manual entry would totally defeat the purpose of doing this.

Thanks so much!

Comment: XSLT is a good idea. Can you post an example of your expected output?

Comment: **If** I understand your XML source document correctly, you will need to import it twice, into two different tables - hence you will need two XSLT stylesheets, one for each import.

Comment: Hi Helderdarocha. So, ultimately I'll need it to output in a table format, with the following columns: itemID, locationID, typeID, quantity, flag, singleton, parentID. All of these are in the original XML except for parentID, which would be 0 or null for nested items, and reference the parent item for nested items.

Comment: @Calvin_xc1 Don't *explain* the format. Going from your sample input write down in your question exactly what output you want to have.

Comment: Updated, hopefully that should clarify what I'm after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSV-style output is actually quite easy and straight-forward to obtain via XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>itemID, locationID, typeID, quantity, flag, singleton, parentID&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//row" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:variable name="p" select="ancestor::row[1]" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@itemID, ', ')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@locationID|$p/@locationID, ', ')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@typeID, ', ')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@quantity, ', ')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@flag, ', ')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@singleton, ', ')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($p/@itemID, '&#xA;')" />
  </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces

```
itemID, locationID, typeID, quantity, flag, singleton, parentID
961254083, 30001161, 17177, 1, 0, 1, 
961256074, 30001161, 27672, 1, 0, 1, 
1270658107, 30002583, 17176, 1, 0, 1, 
1000474513775, 30002583, 17407, 1, 0, 1, 
1000515794105, 30002583, 255, 1, 27, 1, 1000474513775
1000474513607, 30002583, 17406, 1, 0, 1, 
1000515772705, 30002583, 17686, 1, 27, 1, 1000474513607
```

The one thing worth nothing in the XSLT program is this line

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(@locationID|$p/@locationID, ', ')" />
```

Here `@locationID|$p/@locationID` selects the *union* of the current `<row>`'s `@locationID` and that of the container `<row>`. This XPath can return a maximum of two attribute nodes, but the underlying assumption here is that they are mutually exclusive.

It's a little trick that makes the line work in both situation while avoiding a conditional. However, if my underlying assumption is wrong, the result of the expression will be wrong as well.

Read about how `<xsl:apply-templates>` works if you have difficulties understanding the solution.

Comment: But have you understood the solution, that's the question?

Comment: Pieces of it, yes. While working with the file, I realized that there was multiple nesting levels going on in the full xml (which is several times bigger than the sample above). Made a few tweaks to your xslt to have it catch up to 4 levels of nesting. I don't think it'll get any deeper than that, but if so, I'll tweak it further. Also, since only the top level of nesting has the locationID, and nested items can never be in a different location than their parent objects, the union function works nicely. I learn as I go (-:

Comment: That sounds promising. Keep it up! :)